# Install sqlcmd with SQL Server 2014 unattended?

Tags: c++, sql-server, sqlcmd, sql-server-2014

I want the installer I am writing to install an SQL Server 2014 Express instance, and then immediately execute a command on the server.

I have the Configurationfile.ini working properly and it successfully installs the instance perfectly. But this does not install sqlcmd, which I want to use to execute the command.

Does anyone know if there is a way to either tell the server express installer to install sqlcmd, or if there is a separate installer I can run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for SQLCMD for SQL Server 2014, you can download it from [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433) link.